# Start 2013 workflow from 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Who was the bright idiot at Microsoft who decided you shouldn't be able to start a 2013 workflow from a 2013 workflow?  Who ever made this decision should be fired.

Answer (score 0):

No Idea who decided it and in the end it doesn't even matter. But it is possible to start a 2013 Workflow from within a 2013 Workflow with the "Call HTTP web service" Action.

You can read how exactly it works here:

http://www.benprins.net/2016/12/30/sharepoint-2013-workflow-start-a-workflow-using-a-rest-call/